# Highcharts: Previous category data in tooltip

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c98vd98b/ is a solution for displaying a previous value in tooltip.

How can I do this please same but for ?

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
```

for example I want have in tooltip actual and previous month like this.

Tooltip1: "between Jan and Feb is actual value"

Tooltip2: "between Feb and Mar is actual  value"

....

Comment: I don't really understand what you want here. Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/c98vd98b/7/?

Comment: Yes! this parameter **prevPoint.category** is answer for me thank you.